# Getting a list of all project owners from GCP

Tags: list, export, gcloud, owner, google-iam

I am trying to get a list of all GCP projects on the domain and the project owners and export it to a CSV so I can throw it into a google sheet. Getting a list is simple enough, but I can't find a way to get the owners for each project.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
ROLE="roles/owner"
for PROJECT in $(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)" \
  --filter="projectId ~ something")
do
  printf "%s:\n" ${PROJECT}
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
  --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
  --filter="bindings.role=${ROLE}" \
  --format="value(bindings.members)"
  printf "\n"
done
```

For completeness, using the excellent [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which is both more general-purpose and -- I think -- easier to use:

```sh
for PROJECT in $(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)" \
  --filter="projectId ~ something")
do
  printf "%s:\n" ${PROJECT}
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --format="json" \
  | jq -r '.bindings[] | select(.role=="roles/owner") | .members[]'
  printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, Daz. Am I running this from my terminal? I'll admit I am a bit of a noob with this.

Comment: works great, fwiw. had to remove filter (wanted to check all projects), but does the job as advertised. only issue is it outputs `jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot iterate over null (null)` occasionally - didn't dig into it. +1

Comment: Glad it works for you. The `null`s likely result from projects where you're not permitted to retrieve the policy

Answer (score 2):

The problem of applying a `--filter` with `gcloud` is that it'll throw an error if the key does not exist, hence I have applied `jq` to achieve the same.

here is the script I used:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "projectId|projectnumber|parentId|lifecycleState|owners|billingEnabled|billingAccountName"

for project in $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)" --sort-by=projectId)
do
        PROJECT_DETAILS=$(gcloud projects describe $project --format="value[separator='|'](projectId,projectNumber,parent.id,lifecycleState)")
        OWNERS=$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $project --flatten="bindings[].members[]" --format=json |jq -c '.[] | select(.bindings.role| . and contains("roles/owner")) | .bindings.members' | tr '\n' ',')
        BILLING_DETAILS=$(gcloud beta billing projects describe $project --format="value[separator='|'](billingEnabled,billingAccountName)")

        echo "$PROJECT_DETAILS|$OWNERS|$BILLING_DETAILS"
done
```

Save the above file as a shell script and make it executable and run

```bash
chmod +x ./get_list_of_projects.sh
./get_list_of_projects.sh
```

output:

```
projectId|projectnumber|parentId|lifecycleState|owners|billingEnabled|billingAccountName
aerobic-mile-12345|99xxxxxxxxxx|35xxxxxxxxx|ACTIVE||False|billingAccounts/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
alien-lattice-12345|64xxxxxxxxxx|35xxxxxxxxx|ACTIVE|"user:abhishek.das@testorg.com",|False|
am-test|11xxxxxxxxxx|35xxxxxxxxx|ACTIVE|"serviceAccount:am-test@am-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com",|True|billingAccounts/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
```